# RecyclerView not showing items until onTouch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, touch-event, android-motionlayout

I have a restaurants map-based app which when I click on a place marker, a fragment displaying the specific place is created with `RecyclerView` showing reviews about the place and a like button all inside a motion layout, when the fragment is created and the button is not liked (means the specific place showing is not in the user favorites) the recyclerview shows everything fine, and if I press the like button then an animation on the button is occurred replacing the button drawable from unfilled icon to red color filled icon and everything still working as expected.

When I enter the same fragment with the same specific place again, the like button is animated to be filled again since the place is already in the user favorites, the recyclerview does not show the reviews until I touch the view itself and `onTouch` is occurred..
I tried debugging and looking at the recyclerView visibility and it was visible, even the adapter size was not empty so it was supposed to be shown and work fine but it does not..

If I then dislike the place (the like button turns to be unfilled) -> exit the fragment -> open the fragment again with the same specific place -> everything again works fine.

so I am concerned the problem is somewhere around the animation of the like button and it is related to the motion layout..

Any ideas how to proceed with this issue ?

my fragment_detailed_place.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gmm_white"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_detailed_place_scene"
tools:context=".map.DetailedPlaceFragment">


<androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterButton
    android:id="@+id/place_like_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/gmm_white"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_empty_big"
    app:altSrc="@drawable/ic_favorite_filled_big"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Place Name will be here"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:transitionName="place_transition"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/place_like_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="address will be here"
    android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/place_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_favorites"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="favorites will be here"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/place_address"
    app:layout_goneMarginTop="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Rating: 5.0"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/place_distance"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/place_address" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Distance: 5.0 km"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/place_address" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recent_reviews"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Recent Reviews"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/place_distance" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/reviews_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:listitem="@layout/review_list_item"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recent_reviews" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

my motionlayout like button color filling animation scene:

`

```
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/likeButtonTransition"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="250">
    <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/place_like_button" />
</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@+id/place_like_button">
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="crossfade"
            motion:customFloatValue="0" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@+id/place_like_button">
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="crossfade"
            motion:customFloatValue="1" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

`

my code in `DetailedPlaceFragment` which animates the button if the place is in favorites :

```
        ioSCOPE.launch {
            if (mapViewModel.getIfPlaceIsFavorite(place) != null) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    binding.motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
                }
            } else {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    binding.motionLayout.transitionToStart()
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks !